# Control iPad with iPhone (Netflix in particular)

Tags: ipad, remote-control, iphone, netflix

I have searched all over the internet for an answer to this question and have not found anything. Basically, my iPad is connected to my TV in my room and I don't want to have to get up every time a movie or show ends to go to the next one. This would be my primary use for it, but I'm sure I would find many other uses. I would like to be able to completely control my iPad screen from my iPhone (have it appear fully on the phone). Similar to controlling a PC or Mac from an iOS device. Any suggestions? I have an iPad 3rd gen (not Jailbroken) running 7.1 and an iPhone 5s (Jailbroken) running 7.0.4.

Comment: To confirm: (1) Netflix is playing on the TV. (2) The iPad is selecting the things to play. (3). You want the iPhone to control the iPad to select things to play on the TV. Is that right? If so, are you using AirPlay to display Netflix on the TV or the iPad *Remote.app* to control the device (e.g. Apple TV) plugged into the TV?

Comment: The question was already answered previously. Apparently both devices need to be jailbroken. I just haven't been able to jaibreak the iPad because my computer is broken. I guess I'll just have to find a way. Thank you for your quick response Federer.